# kendo numeric textbox mask

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I need to type big numbers in kendonumeric the problem is 3 digit separator only work after lost focus I need 3 digit mask apply during type like http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/

Answer (score 1):

Use a jQuery mask for your inputs

add attribute at element

```
data-inputmask="'alias': 'decimal', 'groupSeparator': ',', 'autoGroup': true"
```

and then activate widget

```
 $('[data-inputmask]').inputmask();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8WvHE/)

Comment: Actually i need to add a feature like jquery maskto kendonumeric